# How to detect a number and split in MS Access?

Tags: sql, string, ms-access

I cannot control these circumstances at the moment so please bear with me.

I pull email addresses from a field called *EMAIL_O*, and sometimes they are completely valid (*somename@domain.com*) and other times they have a 12-character phone number appended at the front (*123-456-7890somename@domain.com*).

How can I, in MS Access, detect which type of field I am seeing and remove the phone number appropriately when pulling in this data? I cannot just take the `mid()` from the 13th character because if the email is valid, I'd be removing good characters.

So somehow I need to detect the presence of a number and then apply the `mid()`, or just take the full field if no number is present.

Comment: Can a person ever have 23Somename@domain.com?  And while I see that this question is tagged as SQL are you open to suggestions in VBA as well?

Comment: No, an email address will never start with a number. Sometimes the email field can be blank, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pattern matching to check whether *EMAIL_O* starts with a phone number.

```vb
EMAIL_O = "123-456-7890somename@domain.com"
? EMAIL_O Like "###-###-####*"
True

EMAIL_O = "somename@domain.com"
? EMAIL_O Like "###-###-####*"
False
```

So you can use that strategy in an `IIf` expression.  Apply `Mid` when *EMAIL_O* matches the pattern.  Otherwise, just return *EMAIL_O* unaltered.

```vb
? IIf(EMAIL_O Like "###-###-####*", Mid(EMAIL_O, 13), EMAIL_O)
somename@domain.com
```

Those were examples copied from the Immediate window.  If you want to use the same approach in a query ...

```sql
SELECT IIf(EMAIL_O Like "###-###-####*", Mid(EMAIL_O, 13), EMAIL_O) AS email
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: Ah I had tried a pattern match earlier but was going about it the wrong way. Didn't know you could use "#"! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Left and IsNumeric functions you can just check to see if the first character is numeric, something like that is below. (Untested code).

```vb
Public Function CheckEmail(strEmail As String)

    If IsNumeric(Left(strEmail, 1)) Then
        strEmail = Right(strEmail, Len(strEmail - 13))
        CheckEmail = strEmail
    Else
        CheckEmail = strEmail
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to get this done. Assume the number format in front of the email **has a dynamic length** you would not be able to start from 13th char as you suggested. Try pattern matching and replacing using RegEx. This would eliminate the entire string finding/cutting/joining operations

Try this:

```
Public Function FN_GET_EMAIL(iEmail As String) As String
    Const mPattern As String = "^[0-9_-]+[0-9_-]"

    With CreateObject("vbscript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = mPattern
        .Global = True

        FN_GET_EMAIL = Nz(.Replace(iEmail, ""), "")
    End With

End Function
```

sample results:

```
?FN_GET_EMAIL("123123123-123123123123-1231231231231EmailWith1123123Number@domain.com")
EmailWith1123123Number@domain.com
?fn_get_email("123-456-7890somename@domain.com")
somename@domain.com
```

in addition you can add a proper email validation or even change the pattern as per your needs without doing a complex string operation.

Answer (score -1):

You could check for a numeric header:

```
If IsNumeric(Replace(Left(Nz([Email]), 12), "-", "")) Then
    ' chop 12 chars
Else
    ' use as is
End If
```

Comment: For some reason this solution yields a data mismatch error when I try it

Comment: You may have Null values. If so, Nz should handle it (edited).